# Which one to prefer - line.lower() vs. word.lower()

Tags: python, coding-style

When I need to split a line, and put all words in a list as lowercase, which one would be the preferred way:

1.)

```
    list = []
    for word in line.split():
        word = word.lower()
        list.append(word)
```

2.)

```
    list = []
    for word in line.lower().split():
        list.append(word)
```

Is there any performance impact? Does it actually make any difference (except the second one being shorter).

**EDIT**
Added the missing `split()`.

Comment: Have you profiled your code and found a bottleneck here?  If not, don't worry about it.  Unless you run into actual performance problems, prefer clarity of expression to speed.

Comment: If you still care which is faster, run some tests with the `timeit` module.

Comment: ! `for word in line` doesn't iterate over words in the line; it iterates over characters in the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something more compact maybe:

```
>>> a = "I AM A DEVELOPER"

>>> a.lower().split()
['i', 'am', 'a', 'developer']
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try `list comprehension`

```
[x.lower() for x in line]
```

will return a list with the words lowered. If you want to omit spaces:

```
[x.lower() for x in line if x.strip() != '']
```

Comment: I thought that too but that's not true.  
    >>> line = "Hello world how are you doing?"
    >>> [word for word in line.lower()]
    ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', ' ', 'h', 'o', 'w', ' ',
 'a', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'y', 'o', 'u', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'i', 'n', 'g', '?']

Comment: If you mean the spacing original code does not handle it either.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about speed, but this doesn't do what you think it does:  `for word in line.lower()`.  It yields you characters, not words.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are calling `lower` and `append` for each word, I don't think it really makes any difference the order in which you call them.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is:

```
words = line.lower().split()
```

this is better than:

```
words = [word.lower() for word in line.split()]
```

If n is the number of words, the first does n + 1 allocations, whereas the second does 2n.

Answer (score 0):

Since list comprehensions have already been pointed out in another answer, here's one other approach:

```
lst=map(lambda x: x.lower(),line)
```

Also, please try not to use variable names like `list` that are already used in Python. That's really bad form and would cause a lot of confusion in any non-trivial project.